# Como Ordenar Lista (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Como consigo ordenar uma List com java e Hibernate?

Tenho uma classe abstrata com esse método

```
public List<T> listarContas(String where) {
    String consulta = "FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName()+ " where "+ where;
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(consulta);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

e tenho o controller com esse metodo que chama a lista

```
public List<Usuario> getListaUsuariosAtivados(){
   listaUsuarios = usuarioFacade.listarContas("(situacao) = 'Ativo'");
   return listaUsuarios;
}
```

Estou usando Java, Hibernate, MySql, e Primefaces.

Teria alguma maneira de fazer um "*Order By*" ou alguma outra coisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode também aplicar ordenação através da anotação "OrderBy" diretamente no atributo da entidade.

```
    @Entity 
    public class Escola{
       ...
       @ManyToMany
       @OrderBy("ultimoNome ASC")
       public Set<Estudante> getEstudantes() {...};
       ...
    }
```

Solução alternativa é aplicar ordenação diretamente na coleção de retorno com Comparable e Comparator.

Answer (score 3):

No JPQL, simplesmente use `ORDER BY` seguido do nome da variável na sua entidade. Segue um exemplo ordenando por `situacao`:

```
public List<T> listarContas(String where) {
    String consulta = "FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName()+ " where "+ where
    + " ORDER BY situacao ";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(consulta);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Por padrão, é uma ordenação ascendente. Se quiser fazer descendente, apenas acrescente `DESC` ao final:

```
+ " ORDER BY situacao DESC ";
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando :D